# Low k-indeks in gam.check regardless how large the basis dimensions in gam analysing spatial data

Tags: r, spatial, mgcv

I'm trying to fit a gam with spatial point data with the mgcv R package. When I check the gam with the gam.check function one of my variables appears to have a too low K (i.e. k-index < 0.6). Doesn't matter how much I increase the basis size the k-indeks will always appear low in the gam.check. I'm fitting a binomial model with 300 observations. I am including an interaction term with the coordinates to control for spatial autocorrelation and using selection=TRUE in the model for component selection. The edf of this problematic variable equals 2.2, so it is among the relevant variables in my model. I guess that if this problem related with choosing the basis dimensions would happen with a non-relevant variable (i.e. edf near zero) I should no worry much since that variable is little influencing my model fit. Am I right?

Could someone help me? I will really appreciate it!

Regards, Carlos

Comment: I just noticed that the edf of that variable is not increasing with larger values of k and its never close to k-1. Perhaps I should not worry about this issue then?